# Django raw SQL not being executed

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

I've written a Django management command to truncate certain tables in my PostgreSQL database (mainly for resetting certain aspects of a dev environment). However, even though Django appears to execute the raw SQL without error, no deletion or truncation actually occurs.

The execution code is simple and looks like:

```
from django.db import connections
cursor = connections[settings.MYDB].cursor()
cursor.execute('truncate myapp_mytable cascade;')
```

The command runs fine, but when I query the table `myapp_mytable` afterwards, all records remain. If I run that same SQL code manually in a direct SQL terminal, it truncates all records correctly. I have multiple databases, which is why I'm specifying the exact database connection.

Why is Django's ORM not executing this SQL?

Answer (score 0):

maybe autocommit has been turned off:

```
from django.db import transaction
transaction.set_autocommit(True)
```